# how to get the non repetitive value from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$array` when i do `print_r()` the out put is something like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => San Pedro Cholula [2] => Colonia Ampliación Momoxpan, San Pedro Cholula ) 
        [1] => Array ( [0] => Veracruz [1] => Papantla [2] => Colonia Papantla Centro, Papantla de Olarte ) 
        [2] => Array ( [0] => Veracruz [1] => Veracruz [2] => Colonia Veracruz Centro, Veracruz ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => Veracruz [1] => Veracruz [2] => Colonia Veracruz Centro, Veracruz ) 
        [4] => Array ( [0] => Morelos [1] => Emiliano Zapata [2] => Unidad habitacional Tezoyuca, Emiliano Zapata ) 
        [5] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => San Pedro Cholula [2] => Residencial Momoxpan, San Pedro Cholula ) 
        [6] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => Puebla de Zaragoza [2] => Colonia Villa de Reyes, Puebla ) 
        [7] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => Puebla de Zaragoza [2] => Colonia San Isidro Castillotla, Puebla ) 
        [8] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => Puebla de Zaragoza [2] => Colonia Popular Castillotla, Puebla ) 
        [9] => Array ( [0] => Veracruz [1] => Alvarado [2] => Fraccionamiento Lomas Residencial, Alvarado ) 
        [10] => Array ( [0] => Veracruz [1] => Alvarado [2] => Fraccionamiento Lomas Diamante, Alvarado ) 
        [11] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => San Andrés Cholula [2] => Fraccionamiento Valle Real, San Andrés Cholula ) 
        [12] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => San Andrés Cholula [2] => Fraccionamiento Rincón de Atlixcayotl, San Andrés Cholula ) );
```

I am trying to get the non repetitive arrays out of it but unfortunately when I use `array_unique()` function it returns only one array out of this

I was trying to use like this

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```

and the out put of this was

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Puebla [1] => San Pedro Cholula [2] => Colonia Ampliación Momoxpan, San Pedro Cholula ) )
```

Which is wrong because i have other array's too that are unique

Please help me out

Thanks & Regards

Comment: i dont believe array_unique is ment for what you intend to do with it.

Comment: What is the expected output for your array?

Comment: @wankr can you suggest what should I do to check the redundant value ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php if you look at those examples they go through mutli dimensional arrays with array_unique. That should help you find your solution

Comment: using foreach and array_intersect maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a comment in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> array_unique is not intended to work with multi-dimensional arrays, it
>   does on 5.2.9.  However, it does not for 5.2.5.

So you have to `serialize` the array first before you pass it to `array_unique` function and then `unserialize` using `array_map` as suggested in [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/946300/4429070)

**EDIT**

In your case it should be as follows

```
$arr = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $array)));
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: oh I'm sorry, haven't seen your comment.

Comment: @OzgurBar bro it did not worked sorry :( , still it is showing repetitive values, for example array 2 and 3 are identical , still it is showing all those

Comment: @OzgurBar my bad bro I was doing some mistake since I am working with lot of array , I fixed it and now i can see it really works fine thanks a lot

Comment: @Vikram no problem, dude. Take care.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_unique don't work for multidimensional array. Now you can get your 
exact answer form here:

 http://schoolsofweb.com/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multidimensional-array-in-php/

 OR

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php

 OR

 http://phpdevblog.niknovo.com/2009/01/using-array-unique-with-multidimensional-arrays.html

 Please read it carefully first and then apply it on your code. If still not solved then let me comment.
```